# How to keep Content provider running for external app

Tags: android, android-service, android-contentprovider, shared

I have a "data hub" that contains a ContentProvider that I wish to access from other external apps. I have so far succeeded in setting up the required permissions and contract classes to access the data through a ContentResolver, which works well enough as long as the data hub app is still running. If I close the data hub, it seems the ContentResolver closes with it (e.g. CursorLoader.LoadInBackgroundv returns null). So I'll trying to find a way to keep the provider active even when the owning app closes. My initial thought is to just run the provider in a remote process Service, but I'm having trouble finding any concrete implementations and I'm too new at this to trust my intuition and burn through my battery. As I understand it this is a fairly common use case scenario, so does anyone know how to make the ContentProvider work for external apps even when the main app has been closed?

#### Edit

Below is the code that I am having trouble with.  When the app containing the `ContentProvider` is running, `cursor` is loaded.  Otherwise, it is `null`.  So to restate the question, do I need to keep the `ContentProvider`'s app running, or can I move the provider into a separate, remote process which remains running even when its app is closed?

```
    private IReadOnlyCollection<ITranslationData> ReadTranslations(string selection, string[] selectionArgs)
    {
        var uri = TranslationConstants.ContentUri;
        string[] projection =
        {
            TranslationConstants.Id,
            TranslationConstants.Name,
            TranslationConstants.Abbrev,
            TranslationConstants.Info,
            TranslationConstants.OsisUrl
        };

        var loader = new CursorLoader(this.context, uri, projection, selection, selectionArgs, TranslationConstants.Abbrev);
        var cursor = loader.LoadInBackground() as ICursor;

        var translations = new List<ITranslationData>();
        if (cursor.MoveToFirst())
        {
            var hasData = true;
            while (hasData)
            {
                translations.Add(new TranslationData(
                    cursor.GetInt(cursor.GetColumnIndex(TranslationConstants.Id)),
                    cursor.GetString(cursor.GetColumnIndex(TranslationConstants.Name)),
                    cursor.GetString(cursor.GetColumnIndex(TranslationConstants.Abbrev)),
                    cursor.GetString(cursor.GetColumnIndex(TranslationConstants.Info)),
                    cursor.GetString(cursor.GetColumnIndex(TranslationConstants.OsisUrl))));

                hasData = cursor.MoveToNext();
            }
        }

        return translations.AsReadOnly();
    }
```

Comment: "As I understand it this is a fairly common use case scenario" -- um, no. "so does anyone know how to make the ContentProvider work for external apps even when the main app has been closed?" -- it does automatically. When another app attempts to use your provider, if you do not have a process running, Android will fork a process for you. However, once nothing is using your provider actively, Android will terminate your process if you are in the background. Beyond that, provide a [mcve] explaining what "the ContentResolver closes with it" means.

Comment: @CommonsWare, edited with the relevant code.

Comment: That's not how you use a `CursorLoader`. You do not call `loadInBackground()` yourself; that is for the framework to use. If you are going to use `CursorLoader`, please [read the documentation on how to use it](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/loaders.html), and use it correctly, with `LoaderManager.LoaderCallback`.